# Syntax Error in FROM clause - SQL Fault

Tags: sql, syntax

I have tried alot of changes from previous posts. Does anyone know what could be cause this?

(I know the code shouldn't be used from a security point of view but its a small local based system)

```
Con.Open();
oleDbCmd.Connection = Con;

OleDbDataReader rdr = null;
OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("select * from Customers", Con);
rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

while (rdr.Read())
{
                Int32 intChech = Convert.ToInt32(cboCustomerID.Text);
                if (intChech == (Int32)rdr.GetValue(0))
                {
                    txtTitle.Text = (string)rdr.GetValue(1);
                    txtSurname.Text = (string)rdr.GetValue(2);
                    txtForename.Text = (string)rdr.GetValue(3);
                    txtAddress.Text = (string)rdr.GetValue(4);
                    txtTown.Text = (string)rdr.GetValue(5);
                    txtCounty.Text = (string)rdr.GetValue(6);
                    txtPostCode.Text = (string)rdr.GetValue(7);
                    txtTelephone.Text = (string)rdr.GetValue(8);
                }
            }
            //PULL DATABASE INFORMATION FOR CAR INFO
           string strSearch = Convert.ToString(cboCustomerID.Text);
           string strSQL = @"select * from Hire if [Customer ID] = '"; 


           OleDbDataAdapter dAdapter1 = new OleDbDataAdapter(strSQL, Con);
           OleDbCommandBuilder cBuidler1 = new OleDbCommandBuilder(dAdapter1);

            DataTable dataTable1 = new DataTable();
            DataSet ds1 = new DataSet();

            dAdapter1.Fill(dataTable1);
            for (int i = 0; i < dataTable1.Rows.Count; i++)

            {
                dgHire1.Rows.Add(dataTable1.Rows[i][0], dataTable1.Rows[i][1], dataTable1.Rows[i][2], 
                dataTable1.Rows[i][3], dataTable1.Rows[i][4]);
            }
}
```

Comment: I don't think you can do that:
select * from Hire if [Customer ID] = ...

What's the database and the language you are using?

Comment: This IF seems to be the problem...

Comment: Look closely at the value of `strSQL`. Exactly *what* should that customer id be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use this code:

```
//PULL DATABASE INFORMATION FOR CAR INFO
string strSQL = @"select * from Hire where [Customer ID] = ?";

OleDbDataAdapter dAdapter1 = new OleDbDataAdapter(strSQL, Con);
dAdapter1.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("[Customer ID]", cboCustomerID.Text);
OleDbCommandBuilder cBuidler1 = new OleDbCommandBuilder(dAdapter1);
```

Or if you don't want to use command parameters you can use this:

```
string strSQL = @"select * from Hire where [Customer ID] = '" + cboCustomerID.Text + "'";
OleDbDataAdapter dAdapter1 = new OleDbDataAdapter(strSQL, Con);
OleDbCommandBuilder cBuidler1 = new OleDbCommandBuilder(dAdapter1);
```

But this is bad practice.